# Effect change in localstorage javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a code to add product to cart when user click the add to cart button

```
 addToCart(){
      var cart = []
      var cartObj = {}

      var cartItem = { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 0 }
      cartObj[this.product.id] = cartItem

      if(!localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
      }

      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

      if(cart.length > 0){
        if(cart.hasOwnProperty(this.product.id)){
          cartObj = cart[this.product.id]
        }
      }

      cartObj[this.product.id]['qty']++
      cartObj[this.product.id]['price'] = this.product.price * cartObj[this.product.id]['qty']
      cart.push(cartObj);
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      console.log('added')
    }
  }
```

I want to have something like this, say user click 3 times on the same product.

```
['product_id': { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 3 }]
```

But instead javascript is doing this

```
[
'product_id': { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 1 },
'product_id': { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 1 },
'product_id': { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 1 }
]
```

Please help

Comment: Probably you need to convert to int the qty var... before the cartObj[this.product.id]['qty']++

Comment: can you update how you are setting this.product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should fix the problem

```
addToCart(){
      var cart = []
      var cartObj = {}

      var cartItem = { 'item': this.product, 'price':this.product.price, 'qty': 0 }
      cartObj[this.product.id] = cartItem

      if(!localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart))
      }

      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

//---------> this check condition needs to be fixed      
      // if(cart.length > 0){
      //  if(cart.hasOwnProperty(this.product.id)){
      //    cartObj = cart[this.product.id]
      //  }
      // }
      let itemIndex = cart.findIndex((val)=>val.hasOwnProperty(this.product.id));
      if(cart[itemIndex]) {
         cartObj=cart[itemIndex];
      } else {
        cart.push(cartObj);
      }

      cartObj[this.product.id]['qty']++
      cartObj[this.product.id]['price'] = this.product.price * cartObj[this.product.id]['qty']
      // cart.push(cartObj);
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      console.log('added')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the triplicate because you're pushing to the `cart` Array every single time the user clicks.

If you want to avoid this, you'd have to check if it's already in the `cart` Array, probably best to check for the `id`

```
var exists = cart.find(item => item.id === this.product.id)
if (!exists) {
  cart.push(cartObj)
}
```